# Spring boot and angular servlet

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a very basic question, but surprisingly I could not find a straight answer.

I am developing a web spring boot project that will run on top of [weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index.html) servlet, packaging as *.war

The client side is still under specification, but one option would be using Angular, since spring boot is not that good at user interfaces.

Here is my question: in this scenario, I would not need Node.js, right? (Everything would run on top of WebLogic)

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: The sad answer is: it all depends on how you do it.

Comment: Is weblogic an absolute requirement ? Spring Boot can be launched as a standalone very efficiently. Actually, it is even awkward to use app servers nowadays, when everybody is trying to make the dev environment as close to production as possible...

Comment: yes, weblogic is a very strict external requirement.. sad to say

Comment: hard life = impossible   OR   hard life = possible, but pain in the ass?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. If you can manage to deploy a war on Weblogic, you'll be good to go. Considering Weblogic was built for that very purpose.

Comment: An angular application, once built, is just a set of static .js, .css and .html files that any web server (including WebLogic, of course) can serve. You'll need NodeJS while *developing* the app (not in production) to build, test and package the Angular app, tough.

Comment: hard life = Spring Boot has been precisely designed to get rid of all app servers like Web Logic. While you still can use Web Logic and Spring Boot together, this combination makes little sense. It's like putting a car in a truck and still trying to drive from the car that is inside. Spring Boot is self contained: all you have to deploy is a jar that contains whatever web server you need, like Tomcat, Jetty...

Comment: @avi.elkharrat.  I understood.. thank you for the info!  Just to be clear, the "hard life" has nothing to do with the Angular, it is just a thing between spring boot and servlets containers...

Comment: @guilhermecgs yep